# drivers of wireless usb adpter bl-wn151

Tags: 12.04

please help me!!!

I HAVE AN CD OF DRIVER OF MY USB ADPTER, THERE IS A FOLDER OF LINUX IN IT BUT DONT KNOW TO INSTALL???

THE FULL CONFIGURATION OF MY USB WIRELESS ADAPTER IS ON:::

www.lb-link.cn/index.php/download/view?cid=195

The output of `lsusb` is

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: HOW DOES IT WORK??

Comment: Please do not use caps lock. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1, terminal will open. Type there this command and post output to your question. PLEASE do not post it here in comments. But this adapter  may work without any drivers.

Comment: ok, nope it require a cd in windows to run

Comment: How about telling us the contents of that linux folder on the CD ?, have tried it without the driver ? Also please edit the caps out of the question it looks ridiculous.

Comment: In ubuntu i don't konw how it work

Comment: i have inserted it in my pc but it does'nt seem to any interference in it

Comment: What ? You don't know how a CD works ? Put it in the drive,. click on it, open the folder named linux and tell what are the names and extensions of the files in side. Try the answer first though in case it works.

Comment: there are lot of file like .mk

Comment: i have given the link to these files

Comment: @markkirby The answer will work, it is the same driver. But on CD it may be packed a bit differently. Hard to guess.

Comment: @DivyanshuJangra Check my answer. It will install the driver without CD.

Comment: how?? tell me!!!

Comment: There is an answer by @Pilot6 right below this conversation, open a terminal and enter the commands one at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these commands in terminal. Very carefully!

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git 
cd mt7601/src
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

Wifi should work after that.

But you will have to re-install the driver after each kernel upgrade.